# How can I fix red symbolic link in Linux ?

Tags: python, linux, centos, symlink

I did `ls -l /usr/bin/python`

I got

[image]

How can I fix that red symbolic link ?

Comment: Find out where python2.7 actually is and use the `ln` command

Comment: I've tried `find / -name python2.7` I couldn't find it.

Comment: I also tried `ls -l python2.7` I got `ls: cannot access python2.7: No such file or directory`

Comment: I've also tried `which python2.7` I got `-bash: type: python2.7: not found`

Comment: Can someone please help me out here ? I'm very new to Linux.

Comment: What is wrong with the link? `python` is a symbolic link pointing to `python2.7` which is usually located in the `/usr/bin` directory. What do you want to do?

Comment: When I see *red*, I thought there something wrong with it. I thought it is pointing to the file that is not there any there anymore.

Comment: maybe you try to reinstall python, it seems python2.7 is deleted completely somehow. In my centos7 machine, this link points to `python2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -l /usr/bin/python` will only show the symbolic link.

Use `ls -l /usr/bin/ | grep python2.7` to see if `python2.7` is in the directory.

The output should be something like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           9 Jun  3 16:39 python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           9 Jun  3 16:39 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     3550168 Jun  3 02:29 python2.7
```

The above shows the binary `python2.7` and two symbolic links pointing to it.

Comment: This is inconsistent with what he described in the question;  if `which python2.7` comes back empty-handed the link **should** be broken.  Not sure why/how this is an accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can enter

```
$which python
```

to see where your Python path is.

You can then use

```
$ln -s /thepathfromabove/python2.7 python
```